# Large dataframes not loading in R

Tags: r, object, dataframe

I have created a dataframe using dbGetQuery with the RMySQL package.  It came in fine and then I saved it fine.  The next day, when I try to load the saved dataframe it says:

```
Error in str(dataframe) : object 'dataframe' not found
```

I only get this for this large dataframe (~1GB).

Is it simply because the frame is too large?

I used the following to create the dataframe from the mySql query:

```
dataframe <- dbGetQuery(connectionString, query)
```

Then I save as follows:

```
save(dataframe, file = 'dataframe.Rda')
```

To load the dataframe I click on the file in RStudio which does:

```
load("~/path/dataframe.Rda")
```

Comment: You'll need to share the exact code you used to both "save" the data frame and then "load" it.

Comment: Can you load it without using the RStudio GUI? The code you describe seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Yes this works fine but not for dataframes as big as 1GB